# C: S_ISDIR not working properly, only the "." and ".." show up as directories

Tags: c, string, io

For some reason when I iterate through all the files/folders in a directories, and check my current selection against S_ISDIR it only works on the "." and the ".." directories. Even though I have 3 files (A, B, C) and 2 folders (subdir, seconddir)

code:

```
//will read all files inside current directory, logic steps down into any sub directory found
int readDir(char * opt_basedir) // opt_basedir is the folder within the root repository of the .exe file, in this case "test"
{
struct dirent *dirr;

 DIR *directory; // used to keep track of current directory
struct stat fileStat; //used for lstat to hold stat info for the document
 directory = opendir("."); // open root
 directory = opendir(opt_basedir); // iterate straight into the selected folder


dirr = readdir(directory);
 while(dirr){

   lstat(dirr->d_name, &fileStat);

   if(S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode))
   {
      printf("only prints of . and .. =>" );
   }
    //if file (open)
    //readCopy(opt_basedir, &block, &offset);
    // else folder
    //function call
     printf("%s\n",dirr->d_name);
     dirr = readdir(directory);
 }


}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here... :(

Comment: Are you sure the cwd is what you think it is?

Comment: `lstat(dirr->d_name, &fileStat);` is relative to your working directory. Your code will ever work if `opt_basedir` is `"." `. Otherwise you need to concatenate `opt_basedir` and `dirr->d_name` before calling lstat().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make sure first that `opt_basedir` is your current working directory.

You could do something like

```
chdir(opt_basedir);
directory = opendir(".");
```

instead of

```
directory = opendir(opt_basedir);
```

Another way is to create an absolute path:

```
directory = opendir(opt_basedir);
/* error check */

while ((dirr = readdir(directory))) {
    char *path = malloc(strlen(opt_basedir) + strlen(dirr->d_name) + 1);
    /* error check */
    strcpy(path, opt_basedir);
    strcat(path, dirr->d_name);

    lstat(path, ...);
    /* other code */

    free(path);
}
```

---

Here is a full test program (Note: the output in `readDir()` only for debugging):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void
readDir(const char *path)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dr;
    struct stat fs;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if (dp == NULL) {
        perror("opendir");
        return;
    }

    printf("%s:\n", path);
    while ((dr = readdir(dp))) {
        if (!strcmp(dr->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dr->d_name, "..")) {
            continue;
        }
        char *abs_path = malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(dr->d_name) + 2);
        if (!abs_path) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(abs_path, path);
        strcat(abs_path, "/");
        strcat(abs_path, dr->d_name);
        if (lstat(abs_path, &fs) < 0) {
            free(abs_path);
            continue;
        }
        if (S_ISDIR(fs.st_mode)) {
            readDir(abs_path);
        }
        printf("\t%s\n", dr->d_name);
        free(abs_path);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s dir\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    readDir(argv[1]);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: So using this method, if I would wish to open a subdirectory of the chdir(opt_basedir) how would I go about that? Nothing seems to be working :x

Comment: So I tried using both the hard path "test/subdir" and dirr->d_name

so... "readDir(dirr->d_name);" neither seemed to actually step into the next folder
@leeduhem

Answer (score 0):

Besides `d_name`, `struct dirent` has a member called `d_type`, too.

Then to fulfill your task, just do sth. like:

```
struct dirent * dirr;
DIR * directory = opendir(opt_basedir);

if (directory) {
    while ((dirr = readdir(directory)) != nullptr) {
        if (DT_DIR == dirr->d_type) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`...` is any code you may want to add. And here `DT_DIR` helps you to check whether it is a directory or not. You don't need to use `stat()` or `S_ISDIR` or so on. (Since you already used `dirent`)

Hope this answer will help you and anybody else who have similar problem.